# Is there an AWS solution that is similiar to IMGix or ImageKit

Tags: image-processing, webp, image-optimization, imagekit, imgix

I am looking for a solution to resize, optimize, and use webp format for images on my site. I am already using AWS and was wondering if I needed to use IMGix or ImageKit to accomplish this or if I could use AWS.

Thank you in advance for looking at my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/fast-and-cost-effective-image-manipulation-with-serverless-image-handler/. Just be aware there is going to be a good amount of work maintaining the Lamdba set up as well.

Just an FYI, I do work at imgix.  But I love creating projects with imgix as well.  I write a lot some of them here: https://dev.to/daletom

So there is certainly a bias there :) But hooking up imgix to your S3, just uploading them through imgix, and using like a react sdk, just makes it so easy.  Depending on your usage, there is a free tier with imgix as well.

Comment: Thanks Tom, this was exactly what I was looking for.